# Amazon-SageMaker - R Kernel: string replace with a single quote is also inserting a backslash in the text, how to avoid that

Tags: r, replace

Consider a string such as:

```
modelfilter <- "month %like% (1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12) & tier %like% (G: 100K-250K|A: 0-1K|H: 250K+|B: 1K-10K|F: 50K-100K|E: 25K-50K|C: 10K-20K|D: 20K-25K)"
```

I want to change it to be like:

```
modelfilter <- "month %in% c('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12') & tier %in% c('G: 100K-250K','A: 0-1K','H: 250K+','B: 1K-10K','F: 50K-100K','E: 25K-50K','C: 10K-20K','D: 20K-25K')"
```

To start with I tried this:

```
modelfilter <- trimws(stri_replace_all_regex(modelfilter, "[(]", "c('"))
modelfilter <- stri_replace_all_regex(modelfilter, "[)]", "')")
modelfilter <- stri_replace_all_regex(modelfilter, "[|]", "','")
modelfilter <- stri_replace_all_regex(modelfilter, "%like%", "%in%")
```

However, in the first replace, I get this as a result on SageMaker, however it works fine on local system:

```
month %in% c(\'1\',\'2\',\'3\',\'4\',\'5\',\'6\',\'7\',\'8\',\'9\',\'10\',\'11\',\'12\') & balance_tier %in% c(\'G: 100K-250K\',\'A: 0-1K\',\'H: 250K+\',\'B: 1K-10K\',\'F: 50K-100K\',\'E: 25K-50K\',\'C: 10K-20K\',\'D: 20K-25K\')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if there's a difference in the versions of R between your local setup and what you have installed on SageMaker?

Another thing to check is that if you're able to get this error on a local Jupyter installation running the R kernel (such as from Anaconda)

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!